# WebRTC: Group video chat - create offer and send answer

Tags: webrtc, p2p, sdp, videochat, groupchat

I have a problem with WebRTC group chatting. [I have achived this on my code]

1. `client-1` create's **offerSDP** for `client-2`
2. `client-2` accepts the offerSDP and replay **answerSDP** to the `client-1` *(the creator)*
3. `client-1` accept and set it as remoteDescription. Now video chat happening.

fine,

**Now `client-3` comes in.**

In my code `client-3` receives `client-1's` offerSDP and emit's ***answerSDP*** to all the client's present in the **server**.

1. Now Both `client-1` and `client-2` will get the ***answerSDP*** from `client-3` and both will recevies `client-3's` video.

**Problem:**

1. `client-1` has [localvideo, client-2_video, client-3_video]
2. `client-2` has [localvideo, client-1_video, client-3_video]
3. `client-3` has [localvideo, client-1_video]. Here this client not knowing about client-2

why? what i have to do here? Helo me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exchange a unique offer/answer pair for each connection. It's not possible to re-use them for different connections.

In your example `client-3` would need to receive an offer from `client-1` **AND** `client-2`. And it would need to send a unique answer to both of those other clients as well.

Comment: 2. Question: Why we need exchange 'iceCandidate'. without exchanging that, by only accepting local and remote description media flows good in my code. I did not use 'addIceCandidate' event in my code. what happen's for client-1 when added client-2's iceCandidate.

Comment: Each candidate can be thought of as an address of the client. It helps the other client to connect. If your testing on the same computer you might be able to connect without exchanging any of the candidates.